# Command line and user input

Tags: c, command-line, user-input

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    float out_radius,in_radius,area, perimeter, in_radius2, out_radius2;
    
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Enter inner radius of ring: ");
        scanf("%f",&in_radius);
        printf("Enter outer radius of ring: ");
        scanf("%f",&out_radius);
        perimeter= (2 * 3.14) * (in_radius + out_radius);
        area= 3.14 * ((in_radius * in_radius) + (out_radius * out_radius));
    }
    
    else if (argc > 1 || argc == 2) {
        in_radius2 = atof(argv[1]);
        out_radius2 = atof(argv[2]);
        perimeter = (2 * 3.14) * (in_radius2 + out_radius2);
        area = 3.14 * ((in_radius2 * in_radius2) + (out_radius2 * out_radius2));
    }
    
    printf("Area of circle: %.2f \nPerimeter of circle: %.2f\n",area,perimeter);
}
```

This is a simple program that calculates the perimeter and radius when given the inner and outer radius as user input. I'm trying to make it so the user has the option to either enter the radius via user input or command line (whichever the user decides to use). I tried to create and if and else if statement to check whether the user enters data in the command line or not. My problem is when I enter the radius via the command line, I get 0 or sometimes the wrong answer as my perimeter and area. What would I need do to fix this?

Edit fixed code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    float out_radius,in_radius,area, perimeter, in_radius2, out_radius2;
  
    if (argc == 3) {
        in_radius2 = atof(argv[1]);
        out_radius2 = atof(argv[2]);
        
    }
   
    else {
        printf("Enter inner radius of ring: ");
        scanf("%f",&in_radius);
        printf("Enter outer radius of ring: ");
        scanf("%f",&out_radius);
    }
    perimeter = (2 * 3.14) * (in_radius2 + out_radius2);
    area = 3.14 * ((in_radius2 * in_radius2) + (out_radius2 * out_radius2));
    
    printf("Area of circle: %.2f \nPerimeter of circle: %.2f\n",area,perimeter);
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the values in `argv` to `in_radius` and `out_radius`?

Comment: Oh wow how I could forget that... Thank you I'll edit the code with my fix.

Comment: You don't need both conditions here: `argc > 1 || argc == 2` If it's `== 2` then obviously it's also `> 1`. And that condition will also be true if `argc == 3`.

Comment: You can't use `argv[2]` when `argc == 2`.

Comment: You should move the area calculation out of the `if`, since it's the same regardless of where the values came from.

Comment: @Barmar Refinement: When `argc == 2`, `argv[2] == NULL` is expected.  Code can _use_ `argv[2]`, but not as a pointer to a _string_ as OP attempts.

Comment: Right, I meant they can't use it the way they're trying to.

Comment: I edited the code to provide something that seemed to work.

Comment: @User234567 I think your calculation is wrong.  For the area of a donut. I'd expect `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argc` is:

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, ... C17dr § 5.1.2.2.1 2

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name ....

**Change logic**

```
if (argc == 3) {
  // Don't need to read inputs. Use argv[1], argv[2] as pointers to strings
} else {
  // Read inputs
}
```

---

Hmmm, OP's changing code - hard to answer a moving target.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought of a solution after posting the question. But your solution seems more simplified compared to mine so I'll try this. Thank you.

Comment: @User234567 Rather than change the question when you think of a solution, leave the question alone and post an answer.  You can answer your own question.

Comment: Got it. Also one more thing, the code I used based on your example prints the correct output if the user inputs in the command line, but I get 0's when I use the user input. I added the code in question at the end of the question.

Comment: @User234567 Better to post your answer as an _answer_ and not an extended question.  Tip: When input does not work as expected, check the return value of `scanf()` calls.  In you case were they 1?  Also immediately print the read in values.  Best with `"%g\n"`.